# Transient discrete time Markov chain on integers: can direction of flow be proven?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm not very familiar with the theory of Markov chains, and I'd like to learn how complicated the following problem actually is.

Let there be a discrete time Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$, where the random variable giving the position on the line is called $Z(t)$. The state is only allowed to change to the nearest neighbours, so the chain is defined by the transition probabilities:

\begin{align}
P \{ Z(t+1)=n+1 \mid Z(t)=n \} &= q_{n} \\
P \{ Z(t+1)=n-1 \mid Z(t)=n \} &= 1-q_{n} \\
P \{ Z(t+1)=m \mid Z(t)=n \} &= 0 &\mathrm{if} \ m \notin \{n-1,n+1 \}
\end{align}

$ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The point is that the transition probabilities $q_{n}$ are not necessarily the same everywhere.

On this system, there is a periodic symmetry. With period $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have: $q_{n+k \cdot N} = q_{n} \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, let's define $p_{ij}^{(t)} = P\{Z(t)=j \mid Z(0)=i\}$ (everything is time-homogeneous) and the corresponding first-passage probability $f_{ij}^{(t)}$, the probability to first reach $j$ from $i$ after exactly $t$ timesteps. The probability to make at least one passage at all at location $j$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
f_{ij} = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} f_{ij}^{(t)}
\end{equation}

Intuitively, the system should run forward if the forward probabilities $q_{n}$ are larger than the backward ones. More formally, I define $Q=\prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{q_{n}}{1-q_{n}}$. For $Q>1$, I expect that:

\begin{align}
f_{ij}&= 1 &\mathrm{if} & \  j>i \\
f_{ij}&<1 &\mathrm{if} & \  j \leq i
\end{align}

Is there any way I can prove this? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is known as a birth-death Markov chain. See here for a resource: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/math100w13/li.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it looks very helpful!